# Differentiating between a ParamArray and other arrays

Tags: vba, excel, paramarray

Is there a way to differentiate a ParamArray from other types of arrays? Right now I'm using TypeName = "Variant()" and LBound = UBound (only one element) to check, but obviously it doesn't work on variant arrays with a single element.

Comment: I don't really get the question. How could this be useful?

Comment: @Rory I want to be able to delegate a ParamArray through a variable number of functions. Right now, every time I pass it directly from one function to another, it adds another level of nesting - which is understandable. I just wanted to know if it was possible to pass it directly.

Comment: A ParamArray is just a Variant array. It only 'exists' in a procedure declaration. You can't pass, or test for, a ParamArray as an explicit type.

Comment: I see. I guess I should just use a normal array instead.

Comment: If the array has dimension 1:1, why to make it array?

Comment: I'm trying to pass a ParamArray directly from one function to another. Doing so would result in the second function receiving a variant array with one element: the ParamArray itself. Every time you delegate the ParamArray through one function like this, it gets nested a level deeper. I'm working on a convoluted workaround at the moment.

Comment: Put the previous comment at the beginning of the question.